# Magento1 to Magento2 import only catalog configuration and its associated product query

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, importexport, simple-product, associate-products

I have 2 website first is magento1 and second is magento2.

so i have import only configurable(with associated product) product from magento1 to magento2 .

so what table to be taken magento1 and import magento2 table

or any query to be magento1 and magento2.

or tool for how to import or plugin

Lets me know

Comment: I guess that best  idea data  from magento 1 using  **import/export** section  and  import that csv data to your Magento  2system

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Import M1 & M2 DB in your local system.
2. Compare fields of respective product tables from M1 & M2.
3. Write query like below(example of sales_shipment table):

```
INSERT INTO m2_db.sales_shipment (entity_id,store_id,total_weight,total_qty,email_sent,order_id,customer_id,shipping_address_id,billing_address_id,shipment_status,increment_id,created_at,updated_at,packages,shipping_label) (SELECT entity_id,store_id,total_weight,total_qty,email_sent,order_id,customer_id,shipping_address_id,billing_address_id,shipment_status,increment_id,created_at,updated_at,packages,shipping_label FROM m1_db.sni6_sales_flat_shipment);
```

Note: Please arrange the fields of M1 & M2 in same order.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: (1) point ok i am import db in my local system. then (2) point  which table to be configurable product and associated product field compare (3) point shipment query is ok  but i need query of configurable and  associate product .